# Running linux containers (lxc) on ubuntu to isolate web server processes (ruby/thin)

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, paravirtualization

I am trying to setup a server where I would be running multiple apps. Mostly internal but could also be open source projects like Redmine. They would all be Rails/Ruby apps/test scripts running on headless browsers. In essence, I am trying to setup a heroku like environment internally and wanted some sort of process isolation between these running processes.

I first stumbled upon chroot jails and then learnt about LXC. LXC seems to offer a better control over plain chroot jails. I have an nginx frontend and I would like to run the webserver app processes (thin/mongrel/webrick) in isolated containers. Usually we simply start off these processes on the local ip address and have nginx proxy to them. What is the best way to get this done? Do people setup a static bridged IP for the container and have nginx point to it? How do I ensure that webservers running in the containers are only accessible to host outside?

Documentation about LXC seems to be a bit sparse. Pointers to some good tutorials or HOWTOs would be greatly appreciated. My target deployment environment is a Lucid 64 bit box.

P.S. I am not a linux guru. So, be gentle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's assume that your own IP is 192.168.1.1, your gateway is 192.168.1.254 and your network is 192.168.1.0/24.

You should make a bridged interface on your host machine, like this in **/etc/network/interfaces** file

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto br0
 iface br0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.1
     network 192.168.1.0
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     broadcast 192.168.1.255
     gateway 192.168.1.254
     bridge_ports eth0
     bridge_stp off
     bridge_fd 3
     bridge_hello 1
     bridge_maxage 5
```

and then install a basic ubuntu in LXC:

```
 apt-get install lxc vlan bridge-utils python-software-properties screen
 mkdir /lxc
 debootstrap oeniric /lxc/ubuntu
 chroot ubuntu
 locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
 apt-get update
 apt-get install lxcguest ssh
 passwd
 rm /etc/mtab
 ln -s /proc/mounts /etc/mtab
 exit
```

create a file **/lxc/ubuntu.config** with the content

```
 lxc.utsname = ubuntu
 lxc.tty = 8
 lxc.rootfs = /lxc/ubuntu
 lxc.mount = /lxc/ubuntu.fstab
 lxc.network.type = veth
 lxc.network.flags = up
 lxc.network.link = br0
 lxc.network.name = eth0
 lxc.network.mtu = 1500
 lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.1.10/24
```

**/lxc/ubuntu.fstab** with

```
 none /lxc/ubuntu/dev/pts devpts defaults 0 0
 none /lxc/ubuntu/proc proc defaults 0 0
 none /lxc/ubuntu/sys sysfs defaults 0 0
 none /lxc/ubuntu/run tmpfs defaults 0 0
```

add to **/lxc/ubuntu/etc/rc.local**

```
 route add default gw 192.168.1.254
```

edit **/lxc/ubuntu/etc/resolv.cont** according your needs.

Then you can create your machine with

```
 lxc-create -f /lxc/ubuntu.config -n ubuntu
```

then start

```
 lxc-start -n ubuntu
```

or stop

```
 lxc-stop -n ubuntu
```

or finally destroy

```
 lxc-destroy -n ubuntu
```

Your new virtual machine will have the IP 192.168.1.10 and will be accessible on the network.

Answer (score 0):

If you rather not want to give external IP adresses to the container or can't:

The [Debian Wiki page on LXC](http://wiki.debian.org/LXC) mentions two variants of accomplishing that using NAT on the host machine. I'm using the approach with [libvirt](http://wiki.debian.org/LXC/LibVirtDefaultNetwork) and have had no problems with that so far.

I don't know what it's like under Ubuntu, but it's probably not that much different there.

The Wiki page may seem like a good information source, but the maintainer himself says that you should rather refer to the file `/usr/share/doc/lxc/README.Debian` for up-to-date information.